# How to send a message to all subscribed users with kik bot

Tags: node.js, kik

I'm just a beginner trying to learn how to write a bot for kik.
I'm trying to write it with the node js framework that kik has provided.

I want to send a message to all subscribed users of the bot; I found this in their docs:

```
bot.send(Bot.Message.text('Hey, nice to meet you!'), 'a.username');
```

but I'm confused as to how they get the username of the subscribed user. I tried using bot.getUserProfile.username, but it seems to be undefined.

Thanks for any help! Also, any tips on how this bot works would be appreciated! I have no web development experience; why does this bot have to be on a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to send a blast to all of your users, I'd recommend using the broadcast API, which allows you to send messages by batches of 100 (instead of 25 for the regular `send()` API).
You can use the broadcast API like this:

```
bot.broadcast(Bot.Message.text('some message'), ['username1', 'username2']);
```

Documentation for this method can be found [here](https://github.com/kikinteractive/kik-node#Bot+broadcast).

As for sending messages to all of your users, you will need to have a list of usernames somewhere (in a database, for example). At the moment, Kik does not provide a way to get your list of subscribers.

Something like this would work:

```
bot.use((msg, next) => {
    let username = msg.from; // Find the username from the incoming message

    registerInDatabase(username); // Save it somewhere
    next(); // Keep processing the message
});
```

You will need to make sure that this is placed before you declare any other handler (such as `bot.onTextMessage()`, for instance).